# ReadPrinter Status C++ and ESC/P

Tags: c++, printing, escpos

I'm having trouble using the C ++ ReadPrinter function. I'm communicating with a printer and I need to get the status and code return from it. I'm always getting a value of 0.

The code I am using:

```
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
unsigned char buffer2[100];


if (!ReadPrinter(hPrinter, buffer2, 100, &dwBytesRead))
{
    std::cout << "Fail to read! " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return FALSE;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Messadge from the bottle xD^ " << buffer2 << std::endl;
}
```

And I also used the code below and I have the same problem.

```
if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, (LPBYTE)pPrnInfo2, dwSize, &dwSize))
{
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    free(pPrnInfo2);
    return FALSE; // Error
}
```

**pPrnInfo2** is NULL.

The printer has bi-directional support.

Comment: Standard C++ does not have a `ReadPrinter` function, so it must be platform specific.  Which platform are you using?

Comment: Did you use a *debugger*?  Using a *debugger* is often times faster than posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Is the value in `hPrinter` valid?

Comment: I'm using windows x64 platform. `ReadPrinter ` refers to _winspool.h_

Comment: I used _debugger_ but the returned value is always FALSE. Always returns 0. I do not understand why.

Comment: Is the value in variable `hPrinter` valid?

Comment: Yes, it's valid! I can send command to print a self-test page.